# Deleting files in git

Tags: git

Is there any difference between:

```
git rm name.txt
git commit -m "message"
```

and

```
#delete the file name.txt normally with the file manager (right-click and delete) and erasign the trash
git add .
git commit -m "message"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If* the only change you're making to that folder is the removal of that file, then no, there is no difference in the end result.  Both will remove that file from the index *and* the working directory.  (`git` will do it for you in the `git rm` case, while you will have done it yourself in the second.)

*However* if you have made any *other* changes in the working directory, then those changes will *also* be staged.  This includes staging files that were previously untracked.  This can be quite annoying as you may accidentally include build output, or perhaps your editor creates swapfiles next to the files it's editing?

For that reason, I recommend the explicit `git rm filename` over `rm filename && git add .`.

Answer (score 3):

Using `git rm` will remove the file from the repository index and will automatically be included with your next commit. By deleting the file manually, you will need to still add the deleted file so that git understands it has been deleted. The `rm` command just does it in one step.

Comment: When I run `git rm name.txt` the file disappears from the working directory. Why? Doesn't that mean that the command removes the file from the file system?

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. Refer the the documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm). It will remove it from the repo being pushed to the server but does actually remove it on your computer.

Comment: @Confiqure Plain `git rm file` _will_ remove the file from the working directory. To remove it only from the index, use `git rm --cached file` instead...

Comment: @twalberg you're correct, I had a couple things backwards in my head! Updated response.